# NServicebus: Programmatic reading of error queue

Tags: azure, error-handling, nservicebus

I’m currently building an application using NServicebus and Azure.

The regular processes are working, but now I’d like to do more about the management and monitoring aspect of the application.

The customer wants to see a dashboard where he can see the health of the application and also be able to correct issues.

What I’d like to do is:

- Detect when things are sent to an error queue (to be able to send an alert to an admin)
- Allow admin to handle messages on error queue from management application, without 
  resorting to the provided command line tool.

Is there a way to programmatically do error handling in NServicebus? I know which errors are transient and which errors might need manual intervention.

Is it possible to plug in logic to the error handling logic of nservicebus?

Is it possible to handle messages on the error queue programmatically?

Thanks,
Erwin

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "dashboard where he can see the health of the application and also be able to correct issues":

Please take a look at ServicePulse (http://particular.net/ServicePulse) for production and online monitoring.
This provides both endpoint health indicators and Failed message indicators (including "Retry" capabilities). 
For advanced debugging and visualization of your process you should also consider ServiceInsight (http://particular.net/ServiceInsight).

Behind the scenes of ServicePulse there's the ServiceControl server which exposes REST HTTP API with programmatic access to audited and error messages.

HTH,

Danny.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was under the impression that Azure wasn't fully supported in ServicePulse. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Erwin yes. Since ServiceControl supports Azure http://docs.particular.net/ServiceControl/multi-transport-support this means ServicePulse will also